# Executing query until there is nothing more left

Tags: c#, async-await

I often query a database to get a batch of items to procees. I do this as long as the query returns some items. I use this pattern quite a lot so I thought I create a small helper so that I don't have to implement this logic again and again.

It's a small class that executes the query until there is nothing more left:

```
public static class Unfold
{
    public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>
    (
        Func<CancellationToken, Task<IList<T>>> query, 
        Func<IList<T>, CancellationToken, Task> body, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = await query(cancellationToken);
            if (result.Any())
            {
                await body(result, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I implemented it exactly this way is:

- all my queries are `async`
- they must always return `IList<T>` (if they return a collection of course)
- I always process a batch at a time that I then mark as *processed*

---

#### Example

The typical use-case is like this:

- get a *batch* of items from a repository
- process this *batch*
- repeat until the *batch* is empty

```
async Task Main()
{
    var numbers = new NumberRepository();
    await Unfold.ForEachAsync
    (
        query: async token => await numbers.GetNumbersAsync(token), 
        body: ProcessBatch, 
        CancellationToken.None
    );
}
```

A test repository:

```
public class NumberRepository
{
    private readonly IList<IList<int>> _numbers = new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 }, new[] { 5 }, new int[0] };
    private int _batchIndex;

    public Task<IList<int>> GetNumbersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(_numbers[_batchIndex++]);
}
```

and the processing method:

```
private Task ProcessBatch<T>(T item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    item.Dump();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

---

What do you say? Is this a good or a bad solution? Is there anything missing (but null-checks)?

Comment: Oh, I see some has donvoted it... how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you definitely need a `null` check here:

> `if (result.Any())`

Else there is not much to comment.

About the usage:

I don't understand, why you create a lambda for the query argument:

> ```
>  async Task Main()
> {
>     var numbers = new NumberRepository();
>     await Unfold.ForEachAsync
>     (
>         query: async token => await numbers.GetNumbersAsync(token), 
>         body: ProcessBatch, 
>         CancellationToken.None
>     );
> }
> ```

Why not just:

```
async Task Main()
{
  var numbers = new NumberRepository();
  await Unfold.ForEachAsync
  (
      query: numbers.GetNumbersAsync,
      body: ProcessBatch,
      CancellationToken.None
  );
}
```

`numbers.GetNumbersAsync` is awaitable already?

Comment: Right, and even to avoid the `null` check at all I definitely need to put the `[NotNull]` attribute there as I always guaratee that collections are never `null`; Unfortunatelly it does not work well with `Task<T>` :-( In this example using a lambda is not necessary, true, but in my application I have some  EF queries there so I wanted to simulate it as real as possible ;-)

Comment: My first try was with observables but I failed to generate them ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: Ah, yes, I remember those things :-). But this one is simple and easy to use.

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't know that but one can use the `[ItemNotNull]` on `Task<T>`, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394258/235671) - if you're using them too.